# position fixed in combination with css3 transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to move the a container containing a fixed element by using -webkit-transform:translatex(80%);

By doing this my fixed elements loses it's fixed style until i remove the transform style..

Does anyone know how I can use transform:translatex without losing my fixed elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding -webkit-transform: translatex(0); to the fixed child element